# Preview captured Image NullpointerException

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, android-camera

```
public void openDialogToAddReminder(final Context context, final DbHelper dbHelper, final int Rem_id, final int Med_id) {
    LayoutInflater layoutInflaterAndroid = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    final View mView = layoutInflaterAndroid.inflate(R.layout.add_reminders_dialog, null);
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(context, R.style.myDialog));
    alertDialogBuilder.setView(mView);
    captureImage = (ImageButton) mView.findViewById(R.id.capture_image);
    captureImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            selectImage(context);
        }
    });
    alertDialogBuilder
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setPositiveButton(dialog_title, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            })
            .setNegativeButton("CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dialog.cancel();
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
    // show it
    alertDialog.show();
}
public void selectImage(final Context context) {
    final CharSequence[] items = { "Take Photo", "Choose from Gallery",
            "Cancel" };
    android.app.AlertDialog.Builder builder = new android.app.AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Add Photo");
    builder.setItems(items, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            boolean result= Utility.checkPermission(context);
            if (items[item].equals("Take Photo")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Take Photo";
                if(result)
                    cameraIntent(context);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                userChoosenTask ="Choose from Gallery";
                if(result)
                    galleryIntent(context);
            } else if (items[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        }
    });
    builder.show();
}
public void galleryIntent(Context context)
{
    Log.i("Context ",context.toString());
    Intent intent = new Intent();
    intent.setType("image/*");
    intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);//
    startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select File"),SELECT_FILE);
}
public void cameraIntent(Context context)
{
    Intent takingPictureCameraintent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    if (takingPictureCameraintent.resolveActivity(context.getPackageManager())!=null)
        startActivityForResult(takingPictureCameraintent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
}
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE)
            onSelectFromGalleryResult(data);
        else if (requestCode == REQUEST_CAMERA)
            onCaptureImageResult(data);
    }
}
public void onCaptureImageResult(Intent data)
{
    try{
        Bundle extras=data.getExtras();
        Bitmap thumbnail = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
        Log.i("Image Camera Bitmap ",thumbnail.toString());
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes=new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90,bytes);
        captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
        saveToGallery(thumbnail);
    }
    catch (Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
}
```

### add_reminders_dialog.xml

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:id="@+id/r1"
                xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
            android:id="@+id/cardview_medicine_image"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            app:contentPadding="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_below="@+id/cardview_medicine_time"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="170dp"
            android:background="#424242"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_camera"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"
            android:id="@+id/capture_image"/>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Getting **NullPointerException** here:

```
captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);
```

I don't know why I am getting captureImage null. As I have define it globally.  Why it is null as I have defined it inside the dialog box.

Comment: Which is the "highlighted" line? I cannot see it in your question. Also post your `add_reminders_dialog.xml`

Comment: captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail); this is highlighted text and also add the xml file @pleft

Comment: Syntax and metadata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well your `captureImage` belongs to the view of your first alert dialog (the one created in `openDialogToAddReminder` method.

I suspect that upon clicking on the `captureImage` to select the image, this dialog gets dismissed so it destroys the `captureImage` reference, hence when the `onActivityResult` is called there is no more `captureImage` object.

You can check the above if you set a [dismiss listener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.Builder.html#setOnDismissListener(android.content.DialogInterface.OnDismissListener)) on your `AlertDialog.Builder` e.g.

```
 alertDialogBuilder.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {

    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Log.d("onDismiss");
    }
});
```

place this code right above:

```
AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
```

**EDIT:**
If you receive on your logcat: "onDismiss" this means that my assumption is correct. Try to resolve it by:

```
alertDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
```

Comment: Ya it run.. output: on capture context on dismiss android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton{424bfa38 VFED..C. ......ID 38,40-554,380 #7f0f0100 app:id/capture_image} when I added System.out.println("on capture context on dismiss "+captureImage); this line

Comment: If you saw on your logcat the "onDismiss" line then please revise my answer above and try to set the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` to `false`

Comment: does the `onDismiss` gets fired even after the `setCanceledOnTouchOutside` has been set to `false`?

Comment: So if you add a `System.out.println("captureImage is null? :  " + (captureImage == null));`  just before `captureImage.setImageBitmap(thumbnail);` you get "captureImage is null? : true" or "captureImage is null? : false" ?

Comment: bro.. I changed the phone and It is working like a charm, Thanks a lot bro,

Comment: Worked with the changes I proposed or your initial code? Probably it needed to remove the app and install it again, so in a new phone it worked correctly.

Comment: again thanks a lot.. I was forget to accept the answer.. Now i have done that.